# SQLite3 query ORDER BY parameter with ? notation

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a query with sqlite3 in python, to be ordered by a parameter column "overall_risk" or "latest_risk" (which is double number)

```
param = ('overall_risk',)
cur = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ? DESC", param)
```

However, I doesn't return the data ordered by `"overall_risk"` (or `"latest_risk"`), 
moreover, when I write the query like:

```
"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY " + 'overall_risk' + " DESC"
```

it does work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL parameters can't be used for anything other than *values*. The whole point in using a placeholder is to have the value properly quoted to avoid it from being interpreted as part of a SQL statement or as an object.

You are trying to insert an object name, not a value, so you can't use `?` for this. You'll have to use string formatting and be extremely careful as to what names you allow:

```
cur = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY {} DESC".format(column_name))
```

If `column_name` is taken from user input, you'll need to validate this against existing column names.

The alternative is to use a library like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to generate your SQL for you. See the [SQL Expression Language tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/tutorial.html).